# Why might artifacts be failing to upload in GitLab CI job?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a GitLab Premium pipeline configuration:

```yaml
# .gitlab-ci.yml
my-job:
  # ... other config stuff; before_script, when: always, image: ...
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "**.json"
      - "*.json"
      - "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/**.json"
      - "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/**"
      - "./**"
```

the `artifacts: path:` section may look silly, but it started reasonable and then -- as a test -- grew to be the above. Getting zero job artifacts uploaded. Super confused and grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Does GitLab complains for artifacts not matching your patterns? `"*.json"` should definitely work. Not sure about `**`.

Comment: @DavideMadrisan thanks for your reply; I figured it out. we had imports coming in who, in a downstream job, were overriding the YAML. So in GitLab there is a Pipeline Editor feature called "View Merged YAML" which I should have inspected more closely :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. If you have `when: always` (default is `when: on_success`) in your config, check to make sure any YAML imports (from other projects/files) are not inheriting and/or overriding the `artifacts:` config.